# Python no module name xyz in home project

Tags: python, import

I would like to ask some help regarding python import part. I would like to develop a small command line tool and I started to create minimal package structure of it.

It looks like this:

```
myTool/
myTool/__init__.py
myTool/mytool.py
myTool/system/__init__.py
myTool/system/argumentparser/__init__.py
myTool/system/argumentparser/ArgumentParser.py
```

when I call in terminal the mytool.py file where the ArgumentParser is imported, then I got this error message:

```
ImportError: No module named ArgumentParser
```

The code looks like this:

```
import ArgumentParser
def main():
--logic--

if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Does not matter whether I try to use

```
from mytool.system.argumentparser import ArgumentParser
```

or

```
from mytool.system import ArgumentParser
```

I got similar error messages about the Python environment cannot see module like this.

I went through a few tutorials and articles about it and I tried modifiy the PYTHONPATH variable without vein.

What is the good solution to reach the project modules easily?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The package is argparse.  That's where ArgumentParser resides.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before the import of ArgumentParser

```py
from system import *
from system.argumentparser import *
from system.argumentparser import ArgumentParser
```

Or just try:

```py
from system.argumentparser import ArgumentParser
```

It may be that python hasn't established these directories as being packages yet, so the **init**.py was not compiled into a .pyc. Or you are referencing the myTool in the import when you shouldn't be. The import should start from the next directory, in this case "system", and not "mytool.system"